# Multiplication table using a list comprehension

Tags: beginner, haskell

I have just started reading through [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) I got up to list comprehension and started to play around in GHCi, my aim was to make a times table function that takes a number `n` and an upper limit `upperLimit` and return a nested list of all the 'tables' up to `n` for example

```
> timesTable 2 12
[[1,2..12],[2,4..24]]
```

the actual function/list comprehension I came up with is

```
> let timesTable n upperLimit = [[(n-y) * x | x <- [1..upperLimit]] | y <- reverse [0..(n-1)]]
```

Any feedback on the above would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time I have really used a functional language, so if there is a better way or something I have missed please let me know.

Comment: Note that `reverse [0..(n-1)]` (even though it isn't needed, as Nicolas' answer shows) could be written `[(n-1),(n-2)..0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function could be simplified a little, and I find it helpful to define functions using declarations, since type signatures are really helpful (although admittedly your example is simple enough that it doesn't matter):

```
timesTable :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
timesTable n u = [[y * x | x <- [1 .. u]] | y <- [1 .. n]]
```

The key thing I noticed was that you were using `n-y`: it should be obvious that this part of the expression becomes the following values in each iteration of y: `[n-(n-1), n-(n-2), ... n-0]`, which is just `[1 .. n]`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that there was something fishy and convoluted with what I had done, feeling a bit silly now because it is very obvious, am just reading the Types and Type Classes chapter which covers declarations, cheers

Comment: We all have silly moments :-) I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you chose `Int` rather than `Integer` or a polymorphic type?

Comment: Oh, not really. You'd choose Int over Integer if you were interested in efficiency, and your numbers aren't too big. You'd choose Integer for unbounded precision, and you'd use a Num class constraint if you wanted to stay flexible (at the cost of having to pass a dictionary around).

Answer (score 1):

We need no stinkin' list comprehensions. And multiplication is overrated as well...

```
timesTable n = scanl1 (zipWith (+)) . replicate n . enumFromTo 1
```